# zatca ubl 2.1 e-invoicing standard tax category with differents rates return errors with sub totals

Tags: xml, invoice, tax, ubl

I'm working on generating ZATCA invoice but something went wrong when I entered three items (invoice lines) with multiple standard rates:
item A : 15%
item B : 5%

in addition to zero rates
item C : 0%

The error appears when there's two rates for standard category in sub total calculation.

So, my question could we have multiple standard rates with ZATCA critiria or not?

check xml :

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<cbc:ProfileID>reporting:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
<cbc:ID>8850</cbc:ID>
<cbc:UUID>03aef88b-8120-4836-b9af-7d3415857b10</cbc:UUID>
<cbc:IssueDate>2023-08-21</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:IssueTime>19:58:15</cbc:IssueTime>
<cbc:InvoiceTypeCode name="0100000">388</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
<cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
<cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>SAR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
<cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cbc:ID>PIH</cbc:ID>
    <cac:Attachment>
        <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="text/plain">NWZlY2ViNjZmZmM4NmYzOGQ5NTI3ODZjNmQ2OTZjNzljMmRiYzIzOWRkNGU5MWI0NjcyOWQ3M2EyN2ZiNTdlOQ==</cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
    </cac:Attachment>
</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
<cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <cbc:ID>ICV</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:UUID>8850</cbc:UUID>
</cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
<cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:Party>
        <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="CRN">1010010000</cbc:ID>
        </cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cac:PostalAddress>
            <cbc:StreetName>شارع 1</cbc:StreetName>
            <cbc:BuildingNumber>8110</cbc:BuildingNumber>
            <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>المربع</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
            <cbc:CityName>جدة</cbc:CityName>
            <cbc:PostalZone>12345</cbc:PostalZone>
            <cac:Country>
                <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
            </cac:Country>
        </cac:PostalAddress>
        <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:CompanyID>310960167200003</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>شركة  سنابل الحصاد التجارية </cbc:RegistrationName>
        </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    </cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
<cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:Party>
        <cac:PostalAddress>
            <cbc:StreetName>صلاح الدين | Salah Al-Din</cbc:StreetName>
            <cbc:BuildingNumber>1111</cbc:BuildingNumber>
            <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>المروج | Al-Murooj</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
            <cbc:CityName>الرياض | Riyadh</cbc:CityName>
            <cbc:PostalZone>12222</cbc:PostalZone>
            <cac:Country>
                <cbc:IdentificationCode>SA</cbc:IdentificationCode>
            </cac:Country>
        </cac:PostalAddress>
        <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:CompanyID>399999999800003</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>شركة نماذج فاتورة المحدودة | Fatoora Samples LTD</cbc:RegistrationName>
        </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    </cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
<cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>10</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
</cac:PaymentMeans>
<cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
    <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
    <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">180.00</cbc:Amount>
    <cac:TaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>Z</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>0.00</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
            <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
    </cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:AllowanceCharge>
<cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
    <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
    <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">200.00</cbc:Amount>
    <cac:TaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
            <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
    </cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:AllowanceCharge>
<cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
    <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
    <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">360.00</cbc:Amount>
    <cac:TaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
            <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
    </cac:TaxCategory>
</cac:AllowanceCharge>
<cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">576.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
</cac:TaxTotal>
<cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">576.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">1620.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>Z</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>0.00</cbc:Percent>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>VATEX-SA-32</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReason>تصدير البضائع</cbc:TaxExemptionReason>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">1800.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">90.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="SAR">3240.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">486.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
</cac:TaxTotal>
<cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">7400.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">6660.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
    <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="SAR">7236.00</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
    <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="SAR">740.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
    <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
    <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="SAR">7236.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
</cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="كيس">2</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">1800.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">200.00</cbc:Amount>
    </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">1800.00</cbc:RoundingAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
        <cbc:Name>رز ابوبنت امريكي 40 كجم</cbc:Name>
        <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>Z</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>0.00</cbc:Percent>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>VATEX-SA-32</cbc:TaxExemptionReasonCode>
            <cbc:TaxExemptionReason>تصدير البضائع</cbc:TaxExemptionReason>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
        <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">1000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
    </cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>02</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="كيس">4</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">2000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">100.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">2100.00</cbc:RoundingAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
        <cbc:Name>رز ابوبنت امريكي 4*10 ك</cbc:Name>
        <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>5.00</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
        <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">500.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
    </cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>03</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="كيس">2</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="SAR">3600.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>discount</cbc:AllowanceChargeReason>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="SAR">400.00</cbc:Amount>
    </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="SAR">540.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cbc:RoundingAmount currencyID="SAR">4140.00</cbc:RoundingAmount>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
        <cbc:Name>دقيق بودرة 45 ك رقم 1</cbc:Name>
        <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>15.00</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
        <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="SAR">2000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
    </cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
```

The validation message:
[image]

let me know where's the wrong?

Comment: Is the subtotal  taxcorrect?  It should be the sum of all the taxes.

Comment: The cac:LegalMonetaryTotal are wrong.  The total tax is $640 and you have $740.

Comment: 740.00 is not tax, it's document level discount.

Comment: The error is a math error.  The sum of all the taxes does not match the document level numbers.

Comment: Make a copy of the XML and edit the LegalMonetaryTotal element and put in correct number.  Then run with edited XML and see if error goes away.

Comment: You are doing everything correctly except the total on the receipt.  The total must be the SUM of the invoice lines.  Your total tax on the invoice lines is 640, but the total tax you put on the invoice summary is 740.  640 does not equal 740.